# Finding the right selector to target a sibling element on :checked

Tags: css, sass

I have a custom checkbox that is an svg sprite in my HTML layout. Everything works fine, I styled everything with scss. Expect I can't figure out what selectors to use to change the color property of .checkbox__icon when .checkbox__input:checked. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work. Is there a way to do it without JS? P.S. I set the fill of the svg to currentColor and the color does change when I do it manually, so that's not the problem. The problem is I don't know what selectors to use here. Thanks!

```
              <label class="checkbox">
               <svg class="checkbox__icon icon icon--checkbox">
                <use xlink:href="public/images/icons/sprite.svg#icon-checkbox-icon"></use>
              </svg>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="checkbox"
                id="checkbox"
                class="checkbox__input"
                checked
              >
             </label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot place icon after input checkbox

```
 .checkbox:has(input:checked)  .checkbox__icon{
    color: red;
  }
```

If you can move icon after input checkbox

```
<label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox__input" checked>
        <svg class="checkbox__icon icon icon--checkbox">
            <use xlink:href="public/images/icons/sprite.svg#icon-checkbox-icon"></use>
        </svg>
    </label>
```

```
input:checked + .checkbox__icon{
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! My issue was - I made a mistake with nested scss selectors. Should've tried regular css first.